# media9 /movie15: Control Which Frame/Picture is Shown When Document is Printed

Tags: printing, movie15

How can one disable movie15 to allow the pdf reader to print a specific frame of the movie? When I print, I get the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{movie15}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includemovie[poster,autoplay,repeat]{10cm}{10cm}{manipulate12.avi}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe first familiarize yourself with this community: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 (provide a so-called MWE)

Comment: Why won't the PDF reader print a page with a movie?

Comment: I know I should write some code, but in this case I believe the question is too generic. However, basically when I send to printing I do not get the first frame of the movie, but the edited image

Comment: `movie15` is obsolete, maybe consider switching to `media9`

Comment: Your MWE cannot be compiled as `hyperref` is missing

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: Is hyperref the video to be uploaded? Of course I don't know how to upload that

Comment: @samcarter I used Adobe Reader 11.0.10 from Macbook and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 17.012.20098 from Windows

Comment: `hyperref` is a package. If I run your MWE I get the following error message: `Package movie15 Error: Package hyperref has not been loaded yet . \begin{document}`

Comment: I believe you can set a custom picture to be used as the standard image, look for **poster** or similar in the manual of media9.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner ok I am working on it. Are you aware if it is possible not to load any external file but to use a frame from the movie?

Comment: And I party disagree with `the question is too generic` since the people who want to answer and want to test their idea before the provide the answer, they have to write the code.

Comment: I don't know. But use **VLC player** for example -- it offers to export any scene as an image (**screenshot**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Don't use `movie15`, it is obsolete, use `media9` instead

That said, you can specify the `poster` image to be used:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includemovie[poster=example-image.png,autoplay,repeat]{10cm}{10cm}{flame.avi}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To convert your desired video frame into an image, the easiest would be to make a screenshot (in case your normal screenshot tool does not work for videos, there is always vlc as an alternative), but there are many other ways: https://superuser.com/questions/135117/how-to-convert-video-to-images

Comment: You can use my comment about VLC Player if you want.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks! I added a short sentence.